# is there any movement on IE browser for forcing them to dismantle it from real world totally?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

IE is literally killing me with crazy CSS and JavaScript bugs. I am really thinking that IE does not provide bunch of different cool feature to user as well as developer, so why this browser even exist.
I want to join if there is any movement on dismantling IE from real world. thanks - ( frustrated common developer )

Comment: i know that engineers here will make this as negative question. but this is really necessary.

Comment: It provides one feature that **no other** browser has. It's so deeply integrated in windows, its security and don't know what can be regulated through the domain configuration. Something like that; I'm no admin. Big companies and Institutions like that. The company I work at, our clients are mostly on IE >80% the rest is almost completely (the newest) Iphone. And I know how annoying it is to deal with both, the old IE and Safari becoming the new Pest. But there is a reason that IE is sticking, it's not out of thin air.

Comment: so what about fixing the IE. can their engineers work 1 hour extra per day to make that IE better ?

Comment: The IE won't be fixed, it can't be fixed. Think about all the hacks that have been used to make something work in various IEs or to distinguish between IE and other browsers so you can address seperately. Imagine how many sites would break if anyone would "fix" the IE.

Comment: so what you telling me is, there is nothing to think about, you just need to keep spending time on stack overflow to find hacks

Comment: What you and your seniors should think about, is how much time you spend on average to fix something that is only a bug on IE, how much your sallary is, and wether these costs are worth it considering the target audience for your sites *(plus your superiors)*. Any Yes, you seem to get paid to spend time on Stackoverflow to find (sometimes insane) hacks for crazy,unpredictable and straight out unreasonable problems in IE; at least that's part of it.

Comment: Which version of IE browser are you using? As we all know, some CSS property and JavaScript function doesn't support the old IE browser, but it might be support IE 11 browser.  Besides, IE 11 is the final version of the Internet Explorer web browser, support ended 1/12/16 for Internet Explorer (IE) 10 and older. Security updates, compatibility fixes, and technical support continue for IE 11. If you meet any IE browser compatibility issue, you could post it on IE forum.

Answer (score 1):

I don't support IE anymore, and neither should you, unless you know your clients to be largely using it. The "browser" is outdated for 6 years and [even Microsoft doesn't want anyone using it anymore](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/2019/02/08/stop-using-internet-explorer-warns-microsofts-security-chief/).

Comment: the thing is my seniors check the entire site on IE, and always , every time , there will be a small bug somewhere in IE only.

Comment: Maybe show them the article? Use Microsoft's authority on the subject as leverage to get them to switch away from that abomination.

Comment: Haleluja.. i was thinking the same for the last past years 